# Salesforce communities not visible in settings

Tags: community, setup

I am trying to search communities but not to any avail.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has been changed to `Digital Experience`.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000356227&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1